# moving WordPress install directory breaks IntelliSense (on WebMatrix)

Tags: wordpress, intellisense, webmatrix

WebMatrix created a default WordPress folder in my C:\Users folder. After I moved it to a different folder location, I had to follow [this post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1174749.aspx?How+can+I+move+the+wordpress+install+directory) to get the site working inside WebMatrix, which is fine.

However, I just noticed WordPress IntelliSense is lost after moving the folder. What I can tell is when WebMatrix opens the moved WordPress folder, it will install the software dependency first. Could it miss out on the WordPress reference or something similar? What's breaking IntelliSense?